# Cocoa Touch - UITableView within a View

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Greetings,

**Problem:**

I have a main view, that already is associated with a xib file, an appdelegate class, and a controller class.

Now, opening its xib file in interface builder, I add a UITableView.

Then, in its controller class, I create the IBoutlet code to use it, let's say: tableView.

---

**Questions:**

1) Where do I go from here in order to populate that table, and then to implement methods to handle events?

2) What is the best way to create/implement a UITableView and then add it to a parent View?

*Thank You very much.
Yohann T.*

*ps: I have looked at a couple tutorials, none showing how to hook it to a parent view.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Where do I go from here in order to populate that table, and then to implement methods to handle events?

A `UITableView` gets its data from a [`UITableViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), and it lets a [`UITableViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) handle events associated with in. Normally, your controller class will implement both of those protocols, i.e.:

```
@interface MyViewController :
    UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Then, in Interface Builder, you can make the association from the controller class to the `dataSource` and `delegate` properties of the `UITableView` object.

> 2) What is the best way to create/implement a UITableView and then add it to a parent View?

The easiest way is with Interface Builder; drag-and-drop the `UITableView` right into your parent view.